# Change date format to a database value

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am displaying a 'date' Database value on a web page. I use Dreamweaver to build web pages which as I'm sure most are aware produces the PHP when binding the  database value to the page. SO I have...

```
<span class="date"><?php echo $row_rsLatest['date']; ?></span>
```

The 'date' column on the SQL database holds the value in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I would like to change the format to '28 September 2016' using the 'dFY' syntax. 
I have tried applying 'date_format' to the above without success.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo date('"d F Y"', strtotime($row_rsLatest['date']));

Comment: try my answers @steve joiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this will may help you,

```
<span class="date"><?php echo date('d M Y',strtotime($row_rsLatest['date'])); ?></span>
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that.

```
echo date('d F Y',strtotime($yourDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php):

```
$date = date("d-F-Y", strtotime($row_rsLatest['date']));
```

Comment: if you don't mind  M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Date() format](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

```
<?php

 echo date('d F Y', strtotime(date('2016-09-28')));

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
28 September 2016
```